# JS injected code displays in the wrong location - How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, document

I've created a random card picker using some code I found online. The problem I have is the location of the code injection.

I want it to display the code in the section rather than of at the end of the body.

The JS looks like this:

```
//find the length of the array of images
var arrayLength = imageArray.length;
var newArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    newArray[i] = new Image();
    newArray[i].src = imageArray[i].src;
    newArray[i].width = imageArray[i].width;
    newArray[i].height = imageArray[i].height;
}
// create random image number
function getRandomNum(min, max) {
    // generate and return a random number for the image to be displayed
    imgNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return newArray[imgNo];
}
// 0 is first image and (preBuffer.length - 1) is last image of the array
var newImage = getRandomNum(0, newArray.length - 1);
// remove the previous images
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var l = images.length;
for(var p = 0; p < l; p++) {
    images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
}
// display the new random image
document.body.appendChild(newImage);
}
```

And the HTML looks like this:

```
<body class="bg-extra-dark-gray small-section text-center">
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 tiny-screen page-title-medium text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                <!-- start page title -->
                <h1 class="alt-font text-white font-weight-600 m-0 letter-spacing-1 margin-5px-bottom">
                    Brainstorm Card Generator
                </h1>
                <!-- end page title -->
                <!-- start sub title -->
                <div class="text-deep-pink margin-25px-bottom">
                    Press the button to display a new card
                </div>
                <!-- end sub title -->
                <!-- start button title -->
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-transparent-white btn-rounded btn-medium text-link-white inner-link margin-25px-bottom" onclick="displayRandomImages();">
                        Display Images
                    </button>
                    <!-- end button title -->
                </div>
                <!-- start image title -->
                <div>
                    <img src="img/info/directions-00.png" />
                </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

See where it says 'start image title' I want the code to display here. I know this is such a noob question, but I rarely code. I just want it to inject inside the section so I can style it.

[Picture of the DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzPQH.png)

The tool is live too, if that helps. https://tools.akanoodles.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do

```
document.querySelector("section").appendChild(newImage)
```

rather than

```
document.body.appendChild(newImage);
```

Plus, don't remove the image like this

```
images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
```

Just write

```
images[0].remove();
```

Comment: Thank you! Such a Noob move.

Answer (score 1):

The very last thing your JavaScript does, is to append the new image to the body of the document. That is at the end of the document.

This line

```
// display the new random image
   document.body.appendChild(newImage);
```

You need to replace it with

```
document.querySelector("CSS Selector, where on the page you like to append your image").appendChild(newImage);
```